# Swift check if an array of objects contains an object of another array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2, contains, equality

I am using two arrays:

```
var facebookFriends: [FacebookFriend] = []

var friendsToInvite: [FacebookFriend]!
```

The first array contains all the Facebook friends and the second one contains objects `FacebookFriend` which have selected in a different ViewController.

Both of the arrays are instantiated correctly in the ViewController.

In the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method I want to change the cell view if the Facebook friend from the `facebookFriends` array is contained in the `friendsToInvite` array.

In order to acheive that, I have tried the following:

```
if(friendsToInvite.contains(facebookFriends[indexPath.row])) {
    // Code to change the view of the cell
 }
```

But I get the following error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[FacebookFriend]'.

Is there any other way to check if this object is contained in the array?

Comment: What kind of value stored in '[FacebookFriend]' ?

Comment: I have created my own class ` FacebookFriend ` and I use the following constructor in order to create an object: 
` init(facebookId: String, facebookUsername: String, profilePicture: NSData) {
        
        self.facebookId = facebookId
        
        self.facebookUsername = facebookUsername
        
        self.profilePicture = profilePicture
        
    } `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FacebookFriend`class must conform to `Equatable`protocol in order to have the `contains()` method to work. This [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Equatable_Protocol/) allows the comparison of objects .

Let's do it with a simplified `facebookFriend`class :

```
class facebookFriend {

    let name:String
    let lastName:String

    init(name:String, lastName:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

}
```

You can conform to `Equatable` protocol quite easily :

```
extension facebookFriend: Equatable {}

    func ==(lhs: facebookFriend, rhs: facebookFriend) -> Bool {
        let areEqual = lhs.name == rhs.name &&
        lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName
        return areEqual
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make a filter using

```
let friend:FacebookFriend = facebookFriends[indexPath.row]
var filteredArray = friendsToInvite.filter( { (inviteFriend: FacebookFriend) -> Bool in
        return inviteFriend.userID == friend.userID
    });

if(count(filteredFriend) > 0){
  // friend exist
}
else{
  // friend does not exist
}
```